How I can disable virt_wifi module and enable the rtl8188eus one?
At my quest using my usb stick I have build and Android kernel with rtl8188eus module fro android running upon x86_64:
mkdir -p /home/pcmagas/dlink-decompile
cd /home/pcmagas/rtlwifiand

git clone https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/common.git
cd common
git checkout android14-6.1-2024-04_r11


make clean
make mrproper
make ARCH=x86_64 defconfig
make menuconfig
make scripts
make

cd ..

git clone https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8188eus.git
cd rtl8188eus

make -C /home/pcmagas/dlink-decompile/common M=/home/pcmagas/dlink-decompile/rtl8188eus ARCH=x86_64 KSRC=~/dlink-decompile/common KDIR=~/dlink-decompile/common
make -C /home/pcmagas/dlink-decompile/common ARCH=x86_64 KSRC=~/dlink-decompile/common KDIR=~/dlink-decompile/common


And I run my emulator with custom kernel:
emulator -avd WiFIUSB -gpu host -qemu -device qemu-xhci -device usb-host,vendorid=0x1903,productid=0x8328 -kernel /home/pcmagas/dlink-decompile/common/arch/x86_64/boot/bzImage -append "root=/dev/sda1 androidboot.hardware=generic_x86_64 androidboot.selinux=permissive modprobe.blacklist=virt_wifi"

But once I do:
adb -s emulator-5554 shell ls /sys/module/ | grep wifi

I see virt_wifi to be enabled but once I do:
adb -s emulator-5554 shell ls /sys/module/ | grep rtl8188

I get no result. Also the only wifi accessible is the AndroidWifi instead of the actual wifi:

So how I can disable the virt_wifi module and how I can enable the rtl8188eus one?
My USB devices are:
$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 05e3:0732 Genesys Logic, Inc. All-in-One Cardreader
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 1a40:0101 Terminus Technology Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 4e53:5407  USB OPTICAL MOUSE 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 2357:010c TP-Link TL-WN722N v2/v3 [Realtek RTL8188EUS]
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub


Also upon android emulator I run an unrooted Android image shipped from SDK manager.
